# No Access-Control-Allow-Origin - Cross Domain

Tags: ajax, tomcat, cross-domain

I am wanting to access a service which is queried from AJAX, but when I call this service indicates me the following in the console browser:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.108.166:8080/LdapRESTEasy/rest/RESTEasyLdap/login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I'm working with Apache Tomcat 6 and create a service which I RESTeasy returns a JSON with user data when login.

My javascript code which contains the AJAX is as follows:

```
function login(){

        var hashNoEnconding = document.getElementById("user").value +'|'+ document.getElementById("pass").value;

        var hashEnconding = base64Encode(hashNoEnconding);

        var url = "http://192.168.108.166:8080/LdapRESTEasy/rest/RESTEasyLdap/login";

        $.ajax({
            url:url,
            type:'POST',
            encoding:"UTF-8",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8"
            },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            accept: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            cacheControl: "no-cache",
            beforeSend: function (request){
                request.setRequestHeader("authorization", hashEnconding);
            },
            success:function (data, status, xhr) {

            },
            error: function (data) {



            }
        });
    }
```

From the apache tomcat server configure the web.xml which recommend adding the CORS filters

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET, POST, HEAD, PUT, DELETE</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
        <param-value>Content-Type, X-Requested-With, Accept, Authentication, Authorization</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposedHeaders</param-name>
        <param-value>Set-Cookie</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportsCredentials</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I also added the apache libraries in / lib:

**cors-filter-1.9.2.jar**

**java-property-utils-1.9.jar**

I have read in the internet about this problem, but still fails to solve

Please, Can I help me? 
Thanks!!

Comment: you can't allow origin * if you are passing credentials, you must instead specify the origin. (the Authorization header is a credential)

Comment: but if I setting cors.supportsCredentials = false .. I don't passing credentials.
Additional cors.allowOrigin = * allows me that requests be made from any domain.

Comment: you're passing an authorization header. By doing so, you have to also set the origin properly and use withCredentials, otherwise the authorization header will not be sent.

Comment: ok, so what should I add in allowOrigin and credentials?
It's the right way:


<param-name> cors.allowOrigin </ param-name>

<param-value> http: // localhost </ param-value>


<param-name> cors.supportsCredentials </ param-name>

<param-value> true </ param-value>

Comment: If localhost is where you are requesting from, i think so. (not familiar with the config file you are using)

Comment: no .. gives me the same error

Answer (score 0):

Yah I found the solution. The problem is in error 500 Internal Server which indicated to me that the parameter sent by request did not reach the service. The same appeared as NULL.
I modify the service to receive a GET and it worked!